# System.OutOfMemoryException error when I open the Sql Server file

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a sql server file ( with the .sql format ) 
when I want open it with SQL Server Management Studio I see a error :

Exepction of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was trown

how I solve this problem ?

TnQ

Comment: How big is this script file? How are you trying to "open" it? Where does it come from and why are you trying to execute such a large script? Is it a file full of INSERT statements? If so, it's infinitely easier and faster to use one of the bulk import mechanisms of SQL Server like the BULK INSERT command or bcp utility to import the data from a data file.

Comment: **Why** do you have such a large script file?

Comment: Anyone reading this in the future, the issue here was probably with the result being displayed causing a memory issue and not the size of the script itself. Quick work arounds are to use Results to Text, or if that fails Results to File

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that the editor of SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) isn't able to handle such large files, due to memory limitations of the UI (for this reason an `OutOfMemory` exception is thrown). Most probably, there are memory limitations related to syntax highlighting, Intellisense and so on.

This problem is known, but I couldn't find anything related to the memory limitations in terms of UI while handling large script files (100MBytes and so on, for example). I found only this document, about the [maximum capacity specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

Anyway, you can run large scripts using the [SQLCMD utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx), executing this line in a command prompt: `SQLCMD -S [Servername] -E -i [SQL Script]`

Comment: OutOfMemoryException occurs for many reasons, not just memory exhaustion. It may well be that syntax colouring fails or some other internal list exceeds its limit and an OutOfMemoryException is thrown.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Absolutely, I forgot to add more detail to the answer, but the exception is indeed related to the editor.

Comment: @DanialHosseini You're welcome. Have you tried running your large script using SQLCMD? Did it solve your problem?

Comment: @DanialHosseini why do you have such a large file? What are you trying to do? There are probably other, easier ways to do it

Comment: What if you get the error using `invoke-sqlcmd` in powershell?

Comment: @GibralterTop I personally don't have experience with large scripts that cause OutOfMemory exceptions by running them in the command prompt or powershell. In my humble opinion, I would just say that this could happen but it would more unlikely that such error occurs by running a large script in a shell (no UI controls, no syntax highlighting, just text), than by running it in an IDE. Of course, there's always a limit to the lines of code SQLCMD can run without issues but we don't know that.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:
1) add RAM to your server (!)
2) check amount of memory assigned to your SQL server
3) increase size of the SWAP file in system settings

Comment: But how I can check amount of memory assigned to my sql server and where is SWAP file and how I can increase size of it ..

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. `.sql` files are scripts. What does "open" it mean? Open it in an editor or in SSMS? Execute it with osql? Why is the script file so large? If SSMS runs on a client machine, SQL Server's memory size is irrelevant

Comment: Tnq for answer , size of file is 300 mb !

Comment: The file isn't large enough to cause RAM problems. The editor can't handle such large files. WHY do you have such a large script and what are you trying to do with it? There are probably other ways to do it (eg use an editor suitable for large text files, execute the script with `sqlcmd`, etc)